# Limit to number of parents an object can have?

Tags: modeling, animation, parent

I have an object with multiple parents to control it. I have a problem though: if I add one more parent object to it, another parent stops controlling it. Is this normal? This is my model:[image]
Each eye is parented to its own empty that rotates it. The reason I did this is because I have a hooked empty on each eye that allows me to change its expression. If I rotated the eye itself, it would distort because of the hooked empty. I parented the eye and the hooking empty to one axis below the sphere so that I can rotate it around the sphere without moving the sphere itself. Now I can only control one empty, or the other. Not both. Is there a better way I could do this?

Comment: I think you'll have to add some explanation of what you mean, because objects can only have one direct parent.

Answer (score 0):

A certain object can only have 1 parent in Blender. You don't need to worry about not being able to control the object the way you want to, because you can also control the parent objects, and so on and so forth. In my example I parented the hooks of the eyes, in which case if both are moved together at the same time will move the entire eye, to a single empty that will move the eye. I did this for both, and parented *those* empties to a third empty that rotated them around the sphere. Then I parented that empty to the sphere itself so that when I move the sphere, everything moves. I thus solved my own problem.